# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 38: invalid start byte

Tags: python, exception, tensorflow, utf-8

I am importing my model from Tensorflow and just want to optimize the trained model using the following piece of code:

```
input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.Open(output_frozen_graph_name, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)

output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
        input_graph_def,
        ["input"], 
        ["y_"],
        tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

f = tf.gfile.FastGFile("optimized_shoaib-har_agm.pb", "w")
f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

And it shows this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>   
>       data = f.read()   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
>   line 125, in read
>       pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))   File
>   "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py",
>   line 93, in _prepare_value
>       return compat.as_str_any(val)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py",
>   line 106, in as_str_any
>       return as_str(value)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py",
>   line 84, in as_text
>       return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 38: invalid start byte

Before it was working fine. I even imported it to Android Studio already. Now all of the sudden I am getting this exception. Is it because I installed something in my machine?

I was able to install the app on my smartphone without any errors. And now it is giving me errors. I am using the same exact code.

Comment: What does Android Studio think is inside the file?

Comment: I was able to install it on my smartphone without any errors. And now it is giving me errors. I am using the same exact code.

Comment: I was using this code last week without any errors. And now I tried running it again and it is giving me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is trying to decode all characters in the file "output_frozen_graph_name". Not sure what changed in the file if it was working for you before, but clearly it looks like some characters are not 'UTF-8' compatible. Now, they can be 'UTF-16' or some other codec format. One way to know is to read the contents in byte format and decode it yourself. Try to read as follows to check the contents:

```
input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.Open(output_frozen_graph_name, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)

output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
        input_graph_def,
        ["input"], 
        ["y_"],
        tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

f = tf.gfile.FastGFile("optimized_shoaib-har_agm.pb", "w")
f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: "One way to know is to read the contents in byte format and decode it yourself" - how can i do this?

Comment: Sorry, but how can I use this line of code that you gave?

Comment: Is it also possible that I installed something into my machine that might have caused this error?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Use the above code and check the contents. Not sure how installing something on your machine would affect Python's behavior unless you have upgraded or using another Python version.

Comment: How do you think the contents were changed? Since before it didn't show this error?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same Python version as you did before? As I recall some tensorflow modules were not compatible with Python3.5. You are using Python 3.5 now, may you have installed Python 3.5. My 5 cents though.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 ever since.

Comment: Did you try changing the code to open file in "rb" mode?

Comment: Yes I did. And it didn't have errors. Why is this? Sorry I retrained the model that's why it took me so long.

Comment: Okay now I remember, I was using a different machine, but I'm pretty sure it is still Python 3.5

Comment: @Chaine when you open a file in binary mode, Python doesn't try to convert the bytes into strings anymore. Therefore you can't get a UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Okay, so I can just use rb instead or r every single time?